# Force of Tension From Lab Setup:

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, torque

I'm kind-of sorry to have to ask this here, but I'm not sure what else to do.

I am to calculate the force of tension from a setup that looks like this:

[image: this].

The right is the pulley that that it is hooked up to from under the axle.

I first set it up as:

ma = Fw- Ft

a= *r

Ft= mg - m*r

But using this I would only be able to find the experimental data, and no theoretical. Could somebody help me out here, I am sort-of lost. If any more information is requested/needed, I will be happy to provide it.

Thankyou for your time.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: What force of tension are you asking about? It sounds like you do not understand the experiment, you do not know what you are doing. Have you asked your teacher? Or a lab technician? Or a classmate?

Comment: @sammygerbil It turns out I had it all right, but thanks a lot guy!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should talk to your teacher/TA/professor/classmate about this.  I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean by "But using this I would only be able to find the experimental data, and no theoretical".  You should just get tension in terms of a bunch your variables and then measure these variables and evaluate the expression to determine the tension.